# How expensive is it to copy a map?

Tags: c++, performance

I have a `map<EntityState, boost::weak_ptr<Animation>>` in my `EntityRepresentation` class. I would kinda want to create a Builder class for the representation, but I have to consider the costs of copying the map.

`EntityState` is cheap to copy since it's just a collection of static functions; `boost::weak_ptr` is also cheap to copy. How about the map as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the number of items it has. I don't think its own members will cause much problem.

Comment: It's a safe guess that, on average, there will be less than seven items in every map.

Comment: I made a small check, map has 12 bytes of memory usage in Visual C++. Assuming pairs will be stored together, it will be 2 separate memcopies first for 12 bytes second for 7*(8+sizeof(EntityState)), I guess its ignorable unless you are doing this thousand times per second.

Answer (score 4):

Don't optimize prematurely. In many scenarios the run-time performance of a builder class will not be the bottleneck.

Generally, the complexity of copying a map is `O(n)`. From the comments, it looks like `n` is small. If you've identified that you *really* need to optimize, then in such a case, using two vectors will be cheaper both in accessing the items, and in the copying.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that no-one else mentionned Copy Elision already.

This concept allows a compiler to elide the copy when possible. It is thus possible that your builder implementation would simply build your `EntityRepresentation` right into the "return" slot and avoid all copy. At which point your worry would be moot.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about it until the profiler says you have to, but generally speaking, there will be one allocation per element in the map, which could have a significant impact.